# lookup field not working on mobile in community

Tags: community, lookup-filter

I have a custom object on the community which has lookup with contact it's working fine in a desktop or if looked from F12 on the laptop. However, when I open the community[Customer community plus] on my mobile this lookup field is not showing any option to create a new contact. Screenshot attached. Please suggest.

[image]
[image]

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Can you please share more detailed version of the image. You can smudge the data if you need.

Comment: updated the image. It is a lookup to contact from a custom object.

Comment: I see the "New Contact" option. Was the latest screenshot from community or desktop?

Comment: Its from laptop in community its visible like this I want to know from Mobile as this +New Contact is not present then how can we create a contact for this custom object record.